# Is it possible to include Linux library in android studio project build on windows?

Tags: android-studio

The idea is that I want to use non-java library compiled for android on Linux, cuz the only toolchain I managed to get working is Linux rather then windows. I don't want to put android studio onto my virtual machine cuz it will be slow or dead, and probably unnecessary. I'm curious what would be the problems if I make a library file on my virtual machine, spit it out into shared folder and then add to my android studio project on windows? Will there be any problems at all? I'm not sure if android studio executes the files before packing them to APK, or if there any filesystem related issues. Can someone elaborate on that, and if anyone knows of a better way to do that - please mention it.

Also to clarify - I don't need to run it on emulator - it will go straight to my device.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're talking about. Do you mean a shared library (.so) that you're building using the Android NDK? If so, it shouldn't matter which of the supported host OSs you built the shared library on, as long as you used the NDK.

Comment: @Michael not sure, i have a program intended for Linux (my ubuntu 18 for example) and I want to compile its source code for android and wrap into java app. I checked that my phone has hardware specs required, and OpenGL version is also acceptable. It lacks some supporting libraries but i will change compiler settings to compile them as well.

Comment: While technically it will end up as .so library it more of an actual app i want to use on android.

Comment: java part is only keyboard and mouse emulation more or less